# Using declaration "not found" in mongodb c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm using the mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1 based on mongo-c-driver-1.6.2.
Using the [latest examples provided on github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/master/examples), I managed to find how to connect the database and how to save documents.

I'm struggling to fetch results using a filter following the informations provided in the [mongocxx/query.cpp example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/query.cpp).

There's a lot of call to a make_document method but I have no class/method/template in the bsoncxx namespace with that name (same problem with make_array).

Heres's the includes, the using directives and using declarations :

```
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/kvp.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/types.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/make_unique.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/optional.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/string_view.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/pool.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/logger.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/exception/exception.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/options/find.hpp>

using namespace mongocxx;
using namespace bsoncxx;

using bsoncxx::builder::basic::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::sub_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::sub_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::array;
using bsoncxx::types::value;
using mongocxx::result::insert_one;
```

The using declarations "not found" :

```
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;
```

Am I missing something obvious ?
Are there more recent examples ?

Comment: Strange, the `make_document` is in [document.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp) and the `make_array` is in [array.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp) which you both included. Could you please provide the actual error message of your compiler?

Comment: Thank you ! You helped me notice that my document.hpp doesn't contain the make_document template (and array.hpp the make_array template).
I'm going to add them and test this afternoon. I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right, as you included all necessary header files needed for `make_document` and `make_array`.
You said in your comment, that the [document.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp) doesn't contain the `make_document` and the [array.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp) doesn't contain the `make_array` template.
This is right for the release `mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1`.

In the current master branch the header files exists as you can see if you follow the source links for them: [document.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp) and [array.hpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp). The examples you use are probably for the new master branch as they are also from a current branch from git.

Comment: The source code comes from the latest release (r3.1.1) from the [mongocxx github release page][1].
  [1]: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases

Comment: I noticed the link to the hpp files you provided leads to the master branch.
The thing is the stable release i'm using is on the stable/release branch.

I can't find the commit where the templates were added, but it explains why I couldn't find them.
Many thanks for you help.

Comment: @Francois: Yeah you're right, they're not in the release branch. They should mention that in the examples, strange thing...