# Mongodb c++ driver issue

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I am getting an error saying namespace "bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::basic" has no member "make_document", I have already added required included as per mentioned in the tutorial.

I am using mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1 version. 
[i have followed example from here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/f3e98ed83f8684670cb29b1a3f004511752d6c34/examples/mongocxx/get_values_from_documents.cpp)

here is what I have tried

```
       #include "maxi.h"
       #include <cstdlib>
       #include <iostream>
       #include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp>
       #include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp>
       #include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/kvp.hpp>
       #include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
       #include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;// here is error 
    using bsoncxx::type;

    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://localhost:27017" } };
```

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DwOk.png)

I have already tested MongoDB driver after compiling and its working perfectly. I need to use make_document option for some reason in order to achieve my goal.
Not sure possible bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document; option may have been removed or replaced with something else which I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current master branch, document.hpp file contains make_document method. 
if I'm not mistaken you are using stable release version.

Take a look here.
[Using declaration “not found” in MongoDB c++ driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540858/using-declaration-not-found-in-mongodb-c-driver)